# How to make TextField to take all available vertical space?

Tags: flutter

`TextField` has `maxLines` property, which defines how many lines are "painted". But what should i do when i don't know the value for this property. Screens are different and i just want that the `TextField` is expanded to its maximum vertically.

```dart
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLength: null,
                maxLines: 100,
                decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
              ),
            ),
            Text("My awesome app"),
)
```

[image]

So here i just made a `maxLines` value big enough to show that it becomes so big that covers the underlying Text widget. If the value is small, then the `TextField` is small too and doesn't take the whole available space. How can i achieve it?

I saw that lots of work has been done on `TextField` recently, which hasn't been released yet: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/27205. Maybe what i want to achieve will become easier after the release. But how can i do this now? Or is there anything simple i'm missing in the already released flutter?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question, this has been made a lot easier recently after [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/27205) was merged.  You should be able to pick up this change by using version 1.3.12 or later.  See the [channels docs](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels) for how to set Flutter to a later channel.

If you are able to use v. > 1.3.12, do this to get a text field that takes up all vertical space available:

```dart
TextField(
  maxLines: null,
  expands: true,
)
```

Comment: Do not forget to wrap it in an `Expanded` widget while using it in a column.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html) set the `maxLines` property of the `textField` to `null` to make the textField set its height according to its content.

Comment: it's not what i asked about, read below the comments under R.Duggan's reply

Comment: I see. Excuse me. What is your intention by having the maximum available space for the textfield? How about placing the TextField in a sizedBox or a Container?

Answer (score -1):

Setting the value of `Lines` to 0 allows it to dynamically increase the number of lines you add if you need more. The downside of this is that it means that the `TextField` begins with a height of 1 line and increases in height as lines are added.

Comment: Firstly, `maxLines` can't be 0. 
Secondly, I want it to be at its maximum from the beginning. I don't want it to be increased during the input. And moreover, setting maxLines to null doesn't stop it to grow and cover underlying `Text`

Comment: My apologies, I meant `lines` not `maxLines`. If you tried setting lines to be 0 and then put the `TextField` within an `expanded then that could give you what you're looking for.

Comment: `TextField` has no `lines` property: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html

Comment: We aren't talking about Android Framework :)